# App closes while executing after compiling with errors, but while debugging it works fine!

Tags: c++, debugging, opengl, sdl, segmentation-fault

Well. that´s the question. Just that.

I got an app made with SDL and OpenGL. SDL opens an extra window (which is the console) additional to the graphical one. When i execute i´m getting a 3 output error, the console tells me. And it gets closed (the graphical one).

But i know this happens when a SIGSEGV signal is received (don´t know how to capture it) and it appears in my IDE (Code::blocks) while debugging. But this time nothing appears, and everything works all right. But when executing it crashes..

What the...

What kind of error can i expect?. Sometimes it gets closed, sometimes it doesn´t. How to know what kind of problem i got?.

Comment: You have an uninitialized variable that gets a fixed value during debug, but is totally random in a release build.

Comment: How can you execute your app if it compiled with errors?

Comment: hey!! yes. could be i have unninitialized variable!! yes! . That´s the difference between debugging and executing!! right!! thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

SIGSEGV is a segmentation fault, you're trying to access memory that isn't accessible to your process.

Assuming you're on a UNIXy system, you should be able to get the program to core dump and then look at the core dump in a debugger; alternatively, use a memory debugger like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to pinpoint the memory management issue that's causing this problem.